# What is the correct /etc/hosts format?

Tags: linux, hadoop, centos

Recently I am started having issue with /etc/hosts file on hadoop nodes. Each host has private & public IP.

Some of the previous setup was with the following format

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

10.0.3.62 client01.dev.abc.com client01
```

and new hosts with following format

```
127.0.0.1   client01.dev.abc.com localhost.localdomain localhost
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

I am still confuse with it. Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not understanding what your question is. What are you asking about?

Answer (score -1):

just do 
nano /etc/hosts

and then add these below the lines which are already present,

192.168.1.15 hadoop-master

192.168.1.16 hadoop-slave-1

192.168.1.17 hadoop-slave-2

These IP addresses should be local/Private addresses.

Comment: Why down vote, this is the correct format as far as I know. Please tell me so that I can improve. Thank You.